# Is it the case that for every $n$, $m$, there is an integer expressible as a sum of $m$ distinct positive integer squares in $n$ distinct ways?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares, perfect-powers

I am not a mathematician, but I learn from various sources that we know that, for every *n*, there is an integer that can be expressed as a sum of two positive integer squares in *n* distinct ways, and similarly for cubes and fourth powers. I also learn that we do not know whether this goes for fifth powers (and every $k>5$?).

My question concerns a generalization of the first proposition: is it the case that,

1. for every $n$, and every $m$, there is an integer that can be expressed as a sum of $m$ distinct positive integer squares in $n$ distinct ways? And
2. the same for squares? And
3. the same for fourth powers?

I have added ‘distinct’ to prevent its being trivial by adding the cube (or square or fourth power) of zero. Since I am not a mathematician, answers will have to be comprehensible to a non-mathematician (but the answers could just be instances of 'yes' or 'no'). Thanks very much!

Comment: FYI, for the number of ways an integer can be expressed as a sum of $2$ squares (although this includes the cases of $0$ being used), see the $k = 2$ part of [Sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function#k_=_2).

Comment: At least $n$ ways or exactly $n$ ways? For the "at least" version, the answer is yes for squares, and yes for higher exponents when $m$ is sufficiently large in terms of the exponent.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks very much for the comment. I meant 'exactly', but I am interested in what you say for 'at least'. If I understand you right, you say that for we know, for every *n*, *m* and *k*, there is an integer that can be expressed as a sum of at least *m* distinct positive integer *k*-th powers in *n* distinct ways if *m* is sufficiently large relative to *k*. Is that right? Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Yes, indeed when $m$ is large relative to $k$, then all sufficiently large integers have at least $n$ such representations. The topics you'll want to search for are "Waring's problem" and "the circle method". Most accounts I find easily talk about how large $m$ needs to be in terms of $k$ for each sufficiently large integer to have at least one representation, but the general method also addresses the problem of the number of representations going to infinity.

Comment: Wow! Fantastic! Thanks very much @GregMartin. I had heard of Waring's Problem, but had no idea of the result you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: @GregMartin I have done the searches you suggested. I found this article: ['On Prielipp's Problem on Signed Sums of *k*th Powers'](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X96900049/pdf). The maths is too hard for me, but I wondered: does it contain a proof of what you said in answer to the 'at least' question? Thanks very much.

Comment: It's probably best to learn Waring's problem, the circle method, etc., from a textbook. Two options are "Additive Davenport" (Davenport's Analytic Methods for...) and Vaughan's The Hardy-Littlewood method. To prove the statement that has been discussed here, it is enough to read the first couple of chapters of either book. I'm sure other people will have other suggestions.